# Why the Django redirects url to undesired page

Tags: python, django, url, redirect

I try to make user registration in Django (version 2.2). I can run local server and fill register form in but when I click on submit button then there is diffrent redirecting and new user is not created. Instead of redirecting to main page ('/') there is redirecting to 'accounts/register/register' and I don't know why. Can somebody help me to find the problem.

Earlier in views.py I used import User from django.contrib.auth.models and changed the code in register.html but the problem was the same. Maybe something is wrong with my settings.py?
in settings.py I added to INSTALLED_APPS = ['users.apps.UsersConfig',] and at the end LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form_register = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form_register.is_valid():
            username = form_register.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('register/')
    else:
        form_register = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, "registration/register.html", {'form_register': form_register})


# urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from users.views import register

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/register/', register),]


# apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'


# register.html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="register" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form_register.as_p}}
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>

    <div>
        {% for message in messages %}
        <h3> {{ message }} </h3>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Django isn't redirecting anywhere. Your actual register view is not even being called.

You have put the form action as "register". That's a relative path; since you started on "/accounts/register/" it will be appended to that, and that's where the form will submit to.

You should do one of:

- Put the full path in the form: `action="/accounts/register/"`
- Better, give the URL pattern a name in urls.py: `path('accounts/register/', register, name='register')`
  and refer to it with the url tag: `action="{% url 'register' %}"`
- Or, just leave the action empty, in which case it will submit to the same page, which is what you want anyway: `action=""`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help. I used all your advice but I have still the same problem. After trying to register a new user I have the following reply in terminal:

```
Not Found: /accounts/register/register    
[31/Oct/2019 20:18:40] "POST /accounts/register/register HTTP/1.1" 404 3847    
Not Found: /favicon.ico    
[31/Oct/2019 20:18:40] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2335
```

To solve problem with favicon I put in urls.py

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

url_patterns=[

path(r'^favicon\.ico$',RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/images/favicon.ico')),]
```

but it doesn't work. The worst problem is the new user is not created.